# Within object B, how to access an object A that has created object B?

Tags: java

My code is of the form below:

```
public class Outer {

    protected int data;
    protected Inner inner;

    protected void run() {
        inner = new Inner();
    }

}

public class Inner extends Outer {

    protected getOuterData() {
        ...
    }
}
```

An `Inner` object will only be created within a method of class `Outer`. Within an `Inner` object, is there a way to access the data of an instance of class `Outer` that has created the `Inner` object?

EDIT: I realise that you can just pass the outer object into the inner object via a constructor but I was wondering if there was another way?

EDIT2: Actually passing the object via the constructor will be OK for what I'm doing.

Comment: You could make `Inner` and actual [Java inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). Also, don't have `Inner` extend `Outer` unless it should.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I'll look into doing it that way, thanks. Inner does have to extend Outer in my actual code which is why I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Outer {

    protected int data;
    protected Inner inner;

    protected void run() {
        inner = new Inner(this);
    }

}

public class Inner extends Outer {
    private Outer parent;
    Inner(Outer parent) {
        this.parent = parent
    }

    protected getOuterData() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I realise I can do this but was wondering if there is another way. I edited my post. EDIT : Actually, this way of doing it will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: which is your goal? Why you need a reference of parent object?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.

```
public class Outer {

    protected int data;
    protected Inner inner;

    protected void run() {
        inner = new Inner();
    }

}

public class Inner extends Outer {

    protected void getOuterData() {
        Outer out = new Outer();        // Create instance of `Outer`
        out.run();                      // Create instane of `Inner`
        Inner inner = out.inner;        // Access data from Outer instance
        int data = out.data;            // Access data from Outer instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Outer {

```
protected int data;
protected Inner inner;

protected void run() {
    inner = new Inner();
}
```

}

public class Inner extends Outer {

```
protected getOuterData() {
    ...
  int localData = data;\\if not already defined with same name
  int localData = super.data;\\if already defined with same name in Inner
}
```

}

PS: I think you are doing something wrong by creating Child class object in parent class method. it may go in infinite loop for creating objects when you initialise child, it will create parent object, which intern create child and so on.

To avoid this make sure not to use run in constructor.